# Is there a formula that can look up a identifying value and then return a numerical total based on multiple specific factors?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm setting up a spreadsheet that tracks welding information.  One of the requirements of this tracking is being able to identify the Welder that made each weld, the type of metal they welded, the joint design for the weld, and then be able to track the number of welds they made using any of 5 welding processes.  I will also need to track the number of welds that were tested for each welder based on all of those same criteria.

I've built a spreadsheet already that works somewhat, but it is very difficult to add new welders or remove other welders without messing things up.  I'm using a very basic =countifs formula that I have to manually change every time a new person is added.

I basically have massive amounts of hidden formulas totaling up everything on one sheet, and then I have to put all that information into a table to show inspection percentages.

I'm not very good with Excel so the formulas I put together took forever and aren't efficient.

Below is an example of the current formula I'm using.

`=COUNTIFS($H$10:$H$10102, "DK", $G$10:$G$10102, "GMAW-P", $C$10:$C$10102, "CS",$D$10:$D$10102, "BW")`

In this formula "DK" is the welder's identifying stencil, "GMAW-P" is the process used, "CS" is the material type, and "BW" is the joint type of the weld. This returns how many BW welds that DK made using the GMAW-P process on CS material.

Below is an example of the formula I'm using to determine inspection results:
`=COUNTIFS($H$10:$H$10106, "DK", $G$10:$G$10106, "GMAW-P", $C$10:$C$10106, "CS", $D$10:$D$10106, "BW", $V$10:$V$10106, "ACCEPT")`

Which returns how many BW welds DK made on CS material using the GMAW-P process that were accepted.

Basically I'm hoping to find a formula that could put this information together without having to manually change the welder ID stencil. I can't figure out how to load a picture on here to show the table I have put together to organize the final data, but I'm thinking that a Vlookup formula may work if it can somehow also provide a total based on the above mentioned limiting criteria.

Here is a sample image:

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Norbia0

Comment: Hopefully the above link works, I'm on a laptop and having a very hard time today.

Comment: Edited the image into the question.

Comment: Other than excel this could be done in google sheets with if's inside an array formula.  I can't see the image. Could you describe the expected result you seek?

Comment: I'm looking to be able to put total numbers of welds made into a table separated out by welder ID (found in column H) material type (column C) joint type (column D) and process type (column G).  I posted a link to the pictures as well if you can't see the one in the post that BigBen helped me out with.  Basically using the picture I would need a table that could say that welder TR has a total of 2  BW welds made on P1 material using the GTAW process.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a summary table showing the **material usage** by `MTRL` type by `PROCESS` type by `JOINT` type by `WID` id, the quickest way would be using **Pivot Table**.

In your source data please add a **COUNT** column putting in the desired quantity used for each material type. Minimum quantity is `1`.

Then you highlight the relevant data range and insert a **Pivot Table**. You can choose to display the pivot table in a **Classic** layout, and highlight each sub-total with a different color like what I did below.

Right click anywhere within the pivot table to **Refresh** the data once there are changes made to the source data such as adding a new WID or PROCESS etc. If your data is not updating correctly, double check if the new data is included in the source range of the pivot table. You can choose to set a large range including some blank rows and filter out 0 value in the pivot table.

[image: Pivot Table]

A formula based approach would be setting out a master table laying out all the `WID`, then `JOINT` tpye per WID, then `PROCESS` per JOINT type, then `MTRL` per PROCESS, and then use the **COUNTIFS** formula to find the counts based on each criteria without hard-coding the criteria in your original formula.

There are **array formulas** to work out the distinct list for each criteria but putting them together into a table is another task on top. In my opinion it is too complicated to do that using excel formulas. A better approach would be **Pivot Table** as explained above. Alternatively Power Query can do the same job.

In addition, you can set up as many different pivot tables as needed using the same source data. Just putting in different criteria in the **Rows** (and/or **Filters** and/or **Columns**) section to build the table as you wish.

Comment: I can't figure out how to show that my question has been answered, but the Pivot table solution suggested by Terry W worked like a dream.  I've been intimidated of pivot tables so I don't normally consider them, but they are far more useful than I realized.  Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: @Spencer good to know that Pivot Table has solved your problem. As I said try to play around with Pivot Table and you realize how efficient it could be when it comes to reporting. The limitation of Pivot Table would be the lack of flexibility of customization. If you want to accept my answer as the solution, you can click on the **tick** mark under the `up vote and down vote` button on the left hand side of my answer.